# pynput how to press combined keys

Tags: python

I wanted to know how I can use the pynput keyboard to press combination keyboard keys like alt left + number 2 / alt left+ number 3

Can anyone help me with this?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key, Controller
import time

PROCESSING = True
STATUS = False

def on_press(key):
    
    global STATUS
    
    if key == Key.insert:
        
        STATUS = True

def on_release(key):
    
    global STATUS
    
    if key == Key.end:
        
        STATUS = False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    keyboard = Controller()
    while PROCESSING:
        while STATUS:
            keyboard.press(Key.alt_l)
            keyboard.release(Key.alt_l)
            keyboard.press('3')
            time.sleep(4)
            keyboard.press(Key.alt_l)
            keyboard.release(Key.alt_l)
            keyboard.press('2')
            pass

    listener.join()
```

Comment: what? Listener is dependency from pynput.keyboard o.o